# How do I play a audio file that is imported with accept?

Tags: javascript, html, button, audio, var

Foe example I have this code

```
<input type="file" id="thefile1" accept="audio/*" />
```

I want to play this audio by using javascript. How can I do?

Comment: I would advise getting acquainted with Web Audio API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one of two ways. Since you asked for JavaScript, you just want so set `autoplay` to `true`. The second way would be to do the same but set `autoplay="true"` on the `video` element itself.

In your case, if you don't want autoplay, you just need to run `.play()` on your video element.

Just to Play the Video

```js
document.getElementById('playButton').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  video.play();
});
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<button id="playButton">Play</button>
```

**Autoplay options**

JavaScript Option

```js
const video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
video.autoplay = true;
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

HTML Option

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay="true">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```